# Consider the linear system $ \begin{Bmatrix} x - z = -2a \\ 2x- y+ 2z= 0\\ 3x+ 4y -19z= -a \\ \end{Bmatrix}$

Tags: matrices

> $$
>    \begin{Bmatrix}
>     x - z = -2a \\
>     2x- y+ 2z= 0\\
>    3x+ 4y -19z= -a \\
>    \end{Bmatrix}
> $$

For which values of a does the linear system have

a) a unique solution
b) infinitely many solutions
c) no solution

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Gaussian elimination,

$$
   \begin{cases}
    x - z = -2a \\
    2x- y+ 2z= 0\\
   3x+ 4y -19z= -a 
   \end{cases}
$$

$$
   \begin{cases}
    - y+ 4z= 4a\\
    4y -16z= 5a 
   \end{cases}
$$

$$
    0= 21a.
$$

Hence if $a\ne 0$ there are no solutions. Else $x=z,y=4z$ make infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In $AX=B$ form $|A|=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 &-1 \\ 2 & -1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 & -19 \end{vmatrix}=0,$ which means this system of Eqs. cannot have unique solution. It will have either many solution of no solution. Let $z=t$,
$\implies y=4a+4t$, putting these in third equation $t$ disappears and one gets $22a=-a \implies a=0$ for consistency. So when $a=0$ yoy have many solutions ans when $a=0$, there will be no solution.